# gradle - proguard errors do not reflect -dontwarn

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

gradle 1.10 on linux on CLI

./gradlew clean

./gradlew assembleRelease

ERROR in stdout...

```
    Note: there were 2 references to unknown classes.
          You should check your configuration for typos.
          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
    Note: there were 5 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
          You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
    Warning: there were 106 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
             You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
:proguardRelease FAILED
:proguardRelease (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 4.689 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I extend an oss package bundled with gradle for release builds ( added jackson.json but not from maven central ).

For some reason, proguard is throwing hundreds of 'org.joda.time... class not found' errors despite the following snips:

```
        release {
             runProguard true
             proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
         }   // in 'build.gradle'

-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.**
-dontwarn ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.**
-dontwarn java.**
-dontwarn com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.**
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.maps.**

    #rcr adds
    -libraryjars  /usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-19/android.jar
    -libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
    -libraryjars libs/jackson-core-lgpl-1.9.2.jar
    -libraryjars libs/jackson-mapper-lgpl-1.9.2.jar
    -libraryjars libs/Parse-1.1.3.jar
    -libraryjars libs/httpclient-1.1.jar
```

stdout DETAIL from './gradlew assembleRelease'  below:

```
    Initializing...
    Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService'
    Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService'
    Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'Object'
          Maybe you meant the fully qualified name 'java.lang.Object'?
    Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
    Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
    Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
    Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
    Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateTime
    Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.ReadableDateTime
    Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.ReadableInstant
    Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$DateMidnightDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateMidnight
    Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$DateMidnightDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateMidnight
    Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$DateMidnightDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateMidnight
    Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$DateMidnightDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateTime
    Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$DateMidnightDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateTime
    Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$DateMidnightDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateMidnight
    Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$DateMidnightDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateTime
    Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$DateMidnightDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateMidnight
    Warn

    ... 100s more in 'org.joda.time.**'

Note: android.support.v4.text.ICUCompatIcs: can't find dynamically referenced class libcore.icu.ICU
Note: com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImplGmm6
Note: com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl
Note: org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory: can't find dynamically referenced class java.util.ConcurrentNavigableMap
Note: org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory: can't find dynamically referenced class java.util.ConcurrentSkipListM
```

The -dontwarn proguard configs for 'org.joda.**' dont seem to work..

I have "-dontnote **ILicensingService" in config and that does not appear to work.

The -dontwarn config for com.google.android.gms.**  not working

The -dontwarn for  java.util.** not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In what file is your "snippet" with the `-dontwarn` flags? It doesn't look like you're ever telling your `build.gradle` file about that proguard configuration.

You have:

```
proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
```

But you should also have:

```
proguardFile 'your_proguard_config.cfg'
```

so that it will use both the default android configuration and your configuration.